# What prevents us from designing material or catalysts to meet the custom requirements?

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, quantum-chemistry

From the perspective of physics, everything is made of atoms, ions, electrons, etc. Since we know the basic interaction between elementary particles, it might be possible to design customized materials or catalysts. But apparently, the real world is more complicated than just adding different interactions together, in condensed matter physics, it is well known that there are new patterns emerging as scaling up, for example, the quasiparticles and superconductor.
My questions are:

1. What is the current view of designing customized materials or catalysts based on elementary laws of physics?
2. From the perspective of ab initio calculation, maybe if we have a powerful supercomputer, we could use Numerical analysis to simulate the real material from the elementary law of physics of each atom. Currently, there is some research about using multi-scale modeling, which introduces some approximation at each level, but I don't see any research of designing materials with multi-scale modeling, is it useful on the subject of material design?
3. I see a lot of research focusing on building a database of materials and trying to use machine learning techniques to find new patterns. Is this a hopeful way to deal with our dilemma?

Comment: You might try asking this question over on [mattermodeling.SE] for another set of perspectives on things (though I don't know whether it would be too basic or too broad on that stack.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We can model fully only a few atoms. We did check all the simple options where we could, if some property is shown in just a few atoms, we know about it already. Problem is that more complex interaction that we cant model.
2. As you add more abstractions and simplifications, predictive power of a model drops. And you need to adapt your model very precisely to effects you want to test for for it to be of any use. A whole new model for a new effect to test is a lot of work. We are in a process, but it takes a lot of time to build such models.
3. Machine learning improves our ability to build simplified models to simulate more particles at once, and it provides some insights about more general approach. But machine learning is in itself a very complex model, very abstract, that is hard to test or improve.

With full models you can simulate a few atoms and get useful prediction about lots of properties, so it is easy to test the model. With simplified models that can model many particles at ones you can tweak it to produce almost any result you want, so years of work is needed to tweak it in a way that testable result is produced. With machine learning, whos only purpose is to produce convincing results, you are out of luck in terms of testing. It can mimic any of the simplified models, on purpose making it look like simulation is doing something right, even if it isnt. The only way to test machine learning approach is to actually find some new catalyst for example. And this way is even slower than making a simplified model by yourself, if the task is known.

Comment: So in short, to simulate the material as in reality, we need a very good supercomputer?

Comment: @Jack direct simulation of atoms 'as in reality' gets exponentially harder as more particles are added. So that you could get to 100 atoms after a century of the whole of mankind building a supercomputer. And to 1000 atoms for turning the whole solar system into a physics-limited supercomputer. I dont think it is the way to go. In simplified models we already can simulate millions of atoms. I would expect more practical results from improving our algorithms in this particular question.

Comment: What about quantum computer?

Comment: @Jack i dont know much about them. The few algorithms we have for a quantum computer can help speed up some very specific calculations, not that useful other than cryptography. We are nowhere close to even knowing what kind of algorithms can quantum computer do. I guess it will help, making the demand for computations more linearly for a 'as in reality' simulation. But i wouldnt bet that it will be able to make it as easy as our current simplified models any time soon.